# Client Side SSL Certification error received on one computer, but not another?

Tags: ssl, https, client

I'm hoping for some help with troubleshooting a frequently received error on my computer. I often try to navigate to very common websites such as https://illinoiscomptroller.gov. This is fine on my work computer, I receive no error. On my laptop at home, I get the NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED error.

I'm not really all that experienced in troubleshooting these types of errors, but I have been getting this message for so long and would really appreciate some help resolving this issue. Every time I google for an answer, most sources suggest there is really an invalid cert, but I know this isn't true. Other answers point to an incorrectly installed cert, but again, I know this isn't the case.

I think the issue lies somewhere in my configuration on my machine. I don't have any fancy firewall set up. What I have noticed is if I click on the "Not Secure" message in the URL part of the Chrome browser, it tells me the cert was revoked by one source.

[image: SSL Cert Error]

On my work computer, for the same website it says it has a valid SSL cert through DigiCert. I looked at my Internet Options SSL Cert providers and DigiCert is on there? Any ideas what I can do to figure this out?

[image: internet options]

Comment: The computer where the certificate is seen valid might not have updated revocation list from the CA

Comment: If your laptop at home a private PC or a company owned/managed? Does the "revoked" certificate contains an URL for an OCSP resolver (online revocation checker).